# Why do I get the error 'str' object has no attribute 'head'?

Tags: python, object, oop

I'm currently working on a module that makes, in short; various text-based graphical interfaces for games.

I have a class called 'interface' and in that class is a function 'comp' (short for computer) that makes a fake computer with fake directories that don't do anything

in 'comp' I have a variable called head that makes the border for the top part of the computer screen.

As I said before, it's text-based, so the border is a string. When I assign the character 'head' is going to use, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\tub_rpg.py", line 14, in comp
    self.head = head
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Does anybody know why this happens? Here is 'comp':

```
def comp(self, head, headLeft, headRight, border, outer, user, folders, size):
        self.head = head
        self.headLeft = headLeft
        self.headRight = headRight
        self.border = border
        self.outer = outer
        self.user = user
```

and here is the file that uses the module, if that's of any help:

```
from tub_rpg import interface as tp

fakedirs = {"Media": ["Picture.jpg"], "Documents":["Profits.xls"], "Backup":["Profits-Copy.xls"], "Games":["DOOM.wad"]}

a,b,c,d,e,f,g, = "_", "[", "]", "[", "]", "ADMIN", 20

terminal = tp.comp(a, b, c, d, e, f, fakedirs, g, g)
```

Comment: Did you mean to make a class instead of a function? If so, you should define `class comp` and then within that define and `__init__()` function that does all the assignments to `self`. As it is, `self` will be the first thing passed to the function, which in this case is the string `"_"`, hence the error.

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you wanted to instantiate the interface with `tp().comp(...)`. But it's not clear since this isn't a reproducible example.

Comment: Print `self` and find out.

Comment: It appears I have forgotten the basics of how self works, lol. Thanks for the quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you want to do something like this as suggested by @Mark

```
class comp:
  def __init__(self, head, headLeft, headRight, border, outer, user, folders, size):
    self.head = head
    self.headLeft = headLeft
    self.headRight = headRight
    self.border = border
    self.outer = outer
    self.user = user

  def test(self):
    print(self.head)
```